# First time building my own LaTeX document

Tags: spacing, formatting

I'm not super new to latex as I used it frequently last semester to write reports but I mostly just used predefined templates given out by our professor so I didn't really need to learn how to do everything. Now i need to build a very simple document that i'm hoping you all can help with!

It's a a single sheet of paper that we post around campus advertising the seminars for the month that we host. I've attached a copy of the "watermark" image in the background. What I need to do it have a defined region of the page underneath the title where we can enter certain information. I've also attached what these 'posters' should look like finished. You'll notice one is a monthly poster, and one is a single poster. **Ideally** I would like to have all the necessary information in one Latex document and have it generate the 'single' poster for each presenter, if that makes sense! [Monthly poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6gRZ.jpg) and [Single_Poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGTqO.jpg), (I couldn't post the watermark because of my reputation score but the watermark is the background + the  text "Cellular & Molecular Basis of Disease Seminar Series"

UPDATED: I've implemented Christians solution (Thank you!). A few follow up questions! How can I change/alter the tabular environment to follow the same margin rules? Second, I tried following an example of someone else's latex code for implementing the text you see at the very bottom of the document under the 'bottompar' environment. the goal is to have that text stationary at the bottom of the page and ONLY in the first half of the page (so it doesn't cover the school of medicine logo). I think the hard part of this is that anything I put in this document needs to be one page long maximum. Lastly, can I define a region of the paper that the text can fill? For instance the top fo the page obivously can't have text because it's used for the title. The bottom bit of the page cant have text because it's a design + a logo. Can i define just that middle region to have text so that things like \vspace*{\fill} will work?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,  %% adjust
contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cmbd_watermark}}
}

\definecolor{redA}{rgb}{0.6, 0.2, 0}
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}

%My Room Definitions
\newcommand{\lb}{\linebreak}
\newcommand{\dom}{Domenici Auditorium, Room 1220}
\newcommand{\hssb}{HSSB, Room 105}
\newcommand{\fitzthree}{Fitz Hall, Room 309}
\newcommand{\fitztwo}{Fitz Hall, Room 203}
\newcommand{\talkdate}[1]{\huge\textcolor{aqua}{\textbf{\underline{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\talkauthor}[1]{%
 \color{redA}#1%
}
\newcommand{\talktitle}[1]{%
  \Large{\textcolor{redA}{\enquote{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}}}%  
}
\newcommand{\hostedby}[1]{%
  \normalsize{\textcolor{black}Hosted by: #1}%
}

\newcommand{\timeandlocation}[2]{%
  \textcolor{aqua}{\normalsize Time/Location: #1,}
  \textcolor{aqua}{\normalsize #2}
}

\newcommand{\talkdata}[6]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
  \huge
  \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{@{}C{0.7\linewidth}@{}}
    \talkdate{#1} \tabularnewline
    \talkauthor{#2} \tabularnewline
    \talktitle{#3} \tabularnewline
    \hostedby{#4} \tabularnewline
    \timeandlocation{#5}{#6}
    \tabularnewline
  \end{tabularx}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\newgeometry{top=5.0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{center}

  \talkdata{January 27, 2017}{%
    \textbf{Farrah Kheradmand M.D.} \lb
    \large \color{redA} Professor, \lb
    \large \color{redA} Baylor College of Medicine}{Cigarette Smoke and DNA Cleavage Promote Lung Inflammation \& Emphysema}{Dr. Xuexian Yang}{12:00 PM - 1:00 PM}{\hssb}
    \vspace{.75cm}

     \talkdata{February 10, 2017}{%
    \textbf{Dr. Carolyn Coyne} \lb
    \large \color{redA}  Associate Professor, Microbiology and Molecular Genetics \lb
    \large \color{redA} University of Pittsburgh School of Medicine}{Antimicrobial signaling at the maternal-fetal interface}{Tione Buranda}{12:00 PM - 1:00 PM}{\fitztwo}
    \vspace{.75cm}

    \talkdata{February 17, 2017}{%
    \textbf{Dr. Mita Das} \lb
    \large \color{redA}  Professor of Pathology, \lb
    \large \color{redA}Burrell College of Osteopathic Medicine}{Role of Adventitial Cells in the Pathophysiology of Pulmonary Hypertension}{ Tom Resta}{12:00 PM - 1:00 PM}{\dom}
    \vspace{.75cm}


\end{center}
\begin{bottompar}
\scriptsize{The Cellular and Molecular Basis of Disease Seminar Series is sponsored by the UNM HSC \lb
School of Medicine, the Office of Research, the Departments of Pathology, Neurosciences,\lb
Molecular Genetics and Microbiology, Biochemistry and Molecular Biology, Cell Biology and \lb
Physiology, Preadtrics, and the Signature Programs.}
\end{bottompar} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is LaTeX, not Latek ;-) Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, my mistake! I keep spelling it phonetically....

Comment: Well, your command `\dte` is missing an `}` at the right, but there are logically errors as well

Comment: `\huge` does not use a brace `{...}` pair usually, but I think they are used here to limit the scope of the `\color` command rather.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible starter, using a `\talkdata` command with 6 (!) arguments, containing the date, name of speaker, title, host, time and location, in this order.

Each is set in a `tabularx` environment, so there might be issues with the color setting, of course.

Change the colours/spacing according to you needs.

A more sophisticated approach would use a key-value interface, but I am out of time, right now.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}


%\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=0.5,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.5,  %% adjust
  contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ente}}
}

\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}
\definecolor{redA}{rgb}{0.6, 0.2, 0}


\newcommand{\talkdate}[1]{\huge\textcolor{cerulean}{\textbf{\underline{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\talkauthor}[1]{%
 \color{redA}#1%
}
\newcommand{\talktitle}[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{\enquote{#1}}%  
}

\newcommand{\hostedby}[1]{%
  \large\bfseries Hosted by: #1%
}

\newcommand{\timeandlocation}[2]{%
  \textcolor{aqua}{\large\bfseries Time/Location: #1} \tabularnewline
  \textcolor{aqua}{\large\bfseries #2}
}


\newcommand{\talkdata}[6]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}
  \huge
  \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{@{}C{0.7\linewidth}@{}}
    \talkdate{#1} \tabularnewline
    \talkauthor{#2} \tabularnewline
    \talktitle{#3} \tabularnewline
    \hostedby{#4} \tabularnewline
    \timeandlocation{#5}{#6}
    \tabularnewline
  \end{tabularx}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{center}

  \talkdata{\today}{%
    \textbf{Jiandie D. Lin, PH.D.} \tabularnewline
    Associate Professor \tabularnewline
    Life Sciences}{Some interesting new ideas}{Some person}{15 pm}{Some place}

  \talkdata{Tomorrow}{%
    \textbf{Jiandie D. Lin, PH.D.} \tabularnewline
    Associate Professor \tabularnewline
    Life Sciences}{Some other interesting new ideas}{Some other person}{16 pm}{Right here!}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty exactly what I was looking for I think!I'll look into the "Key-value" interface since I haven't heard of that. My last question is, how can I modify this to expand the margins to almost the end of the page? This will eventually be a large poster so We want to fill the entire space. Also, theres a bit of text (I added it to my original post and code with your changes) that needs to be added to the bottom of the document and should be stationary. only the bottom left corner of the page. Can  use the tabular environment for this as well?

Comment: @ovp: Increase from `0.7\linewidth` to `0.99\linewidth` and change the margins with `\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}` (just for example). This will increase the `\linewidth` itself.